# Логарифмическое решение two sum

Tags: алгоритм, time-complexity

Решая задачу two sum 2: input array is sorted на leetcode подумал - а нельзя ли совместить binary search и two pointers. В итоге получился код ниже; похоже, что сложность O(logN). Подтвердите или опровергните мое утверждение.

```py
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, numbers: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        left = 0
        right = len(numbers) - 1
        while left < right:
            current = numbers[left] + numbers[right]
            if current == target:
                return [left+1, right+1]
            mid = (right + left) >> 1
            if current < target:
                while numbers[mid] + numbers[right] > target and mid > left+1:
                    mid = (left + mid) >> 1
                left = mid
            else:
                while numbers[mid] + numbers[left] < target and mid < right-1:
                    mid = (right + mid) >> 1
                right = mid
```

Не могли бы люди прошареннее меня рассмотреть также худший, средний и лучший случаи?

Comment: Алгоритм не работает, рассматривать случаи не нужно. target 30/ [6, 9, 14, 16, 17, 20, 22, 23, 28, 38] - выход за массив [9, 10, 18, 20, 32, 36, 37, 37, 44, 49] - зацикливание

Comment: Видать на leet code плохо сделана система тестов, раз такое пропустила. Я и не заметил, думал - раз все тесты прошло, то все граничные случаи тоже учтены

Comment: Для любого алгоритма, который пытается решить задачу "two sum" быстрее чем за линейное время, можно предъявить набор тестов, на одном из которых он будет выдавать неправильное решение. От того насколько хитрый код вы пишете, это не зависит. Просто если алгоритм слишком быстрый, он ошибается. Могу показать как это сделать, если интересно. Никакого волшебства, только правильно подобранные данные.